# Create dummy variable if a dataframe contains rows from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to create a dummy variable based on if df1 is contained within df2. Note that df2 has columns more than just the columns in df1.

e.g.:

df1:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 0 |

df2:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | E |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | F |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | G |

Resulting in:
df2:

| A | B | C | D | Dummy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | E | 1 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | F | 1 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | G | 0 |

Any good approaches I should consider?

I've tried using an ifelse function applied to the dataframe, but I suspect I've coded it wrong. Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to add a column called "dummy" to df1, then join with df2 on all variables of df1.

```
df1$dummy <- 1
library(dplyr)
dplyr::left_join(df2, df1) %>% 
    mutate(dummy = ifelse(is.na(dummy), 0, dummy))

# Joining, by = c("A", "B", "C")
# A B C D dummy
# 1 2 3 E     1
# 4 5 6 F     1
# 7 8 9 G     0
```

By default left_join joins using all commonly named variables, but this can be modified as required.

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Any way to do this if the rows of Df1 have additional copies of rows from Df2?